# How to access MR job counters after job completion?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have a MR job which runs fine in the cluster.

After the job completion I'm able to get YARN logs but I couldn't find the MR job counters like no of input records, output records.

Is it possible to get that information after job completion?